# Webaudio - Record and download the output of a webaudio audioNode

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, mediarecorder, audiocontext

I would like to record the output of my audio context so that the user can download it.

I have been doing research into how this might be possible. There are various answers on stackoverflow. For example this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207996/web-audio-api-record-audio-node).

Many of the answers seem to point to using this project: https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs.

However RecorderJs is no longer active and infact has links to [scam websites](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues/206) in the Readme. So I am hesitant to use it.

[Other stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53069676/2300211)  seem to suggest you can use a MediaRecorder to download the output of an audionode.

I wanted to know if there is some sort of standard I should be adopting to record and download the output of an audionode?

Answer (score 1):

Hello the approach that worked best for me was largely based off this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53069676/2300211.

- connect your audioNode to MediaStreamDestinationNode.
- conect the stream of the MediaStreamDestinationNode to a MediaRecorder.
- Play your audio node and use the Media recorder ondata to write it to a blob.
- Put the blob in a HTML audio element ( see: https://github.com/mdn/web-dictaphone/blob/gh-pages/scripts/app.js#L82)